# CSS Clip path alternative for accordion

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I'm trying to build an accordion that opens from the following view.

[image: Closed accordion]

To.

[image: Opened accordion]

Which is opened on closed via clicking a 'Project' thumbnail (shown top left).

I am currently (somewhat achieving this via a clip-path on the accordion div)

```
.accordion {
  width: 100%;
  height: 80vh;
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px black;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 82% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 
  100%, 0 25%, 25% 25%, 25% 20%, 22.5% 17.5%, 25% 15%);
  clip-path: polygon(25% 0, 82% 0, 100% 0, 100% 100%, 0 100%, 0 
  25%, 25% 25%, 25% 20%, 22.5% 17.5%, 25% 15%);
}
```

However I've been running into a lot of problems with the overlay displaying on-top of the project thumbnail when opened. As-well as issues with responsiveness.

Is there an alternative way to achieve this without the clip path? or a way to optimise what i'm currently doing?

Comment: Thanks. I suggest you have a look at [ask], then revise to put your CSS and a simple HTML sample in a demo using the editor. It's a bit hard to work something like this from just some styles.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong using `clip-path`, but you need to setup some variables and calculate it accordingly, instead of using only percentage, here's an example:

You can play around with the varaibles, and feel free to use `Full page` and change the window size, the dimension of the box should be fixed.

> FYI, you can always set the dimension of the box using javascript such as `document.querySeletor('.accordion').style.setProperty('--width', '300px')` etc.

```css
body {
  background-color: salmon;
}

.accordion {
  /* the width of the box */
  --width: 200px;
  
  /* the height of the box */
  --height: 100px;
  
  /* the distance between the bottom of the box to the arrow center vertically */
  --arrow-dist: 20px;
  
  width: 100%;
  height: calc(100vh - 16px);
  background-color: white;
  box-shadow: 10px 10px black;
  position: relative;
  clip-path: polygon(
    var(--width) 0, 
    100% 0, 
    100% 100%, 
    0 100%, 
    0 var(--height), 
    var(--width) var(--height), 
    var(--width) calc(var(--height) - var(--arrow-dist) + 10px), 
    calc(var(--width) - 20px) calc(var(--height) - var(--arrow-dist)),
    var(--width) calc(var(--height) - var(--arrow-dist) - 10px)
  );
}
```

```html
<div class="accordion"></div>
```